# AWS CDK update/add lifecycle to existing S3 bucket using custom source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I created an S3 bucket but now I would like to update/add lifecycle policies to it using CDK.
Currently I can import this bucket to a new stack file.

```
const testBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'TestBucket', {
            bucketArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx'});
```

How can I use `AwsCustomResource` to update/add lifecycle policies? For example, for `prefix = long`, I want those objects to expire in 7 days, and for `prefix = short`, I want them to expire in 3 days.

Or is there a general way of updating an existing S3 bucket in a new stack with CDK?

Comment: Have you considered importing the S3 bucket into your stack, using resource importing? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I'm new to CDK and S3, so I'm really not sure what's the best approach here. I did a lot of googling and found the approach mentioned above made most sense to me. If you don't mind, could you please elaborate on how to use resource importing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you create the bucket? Was it created manually, and it's not part of another stack?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth Yes I created the bucket manually and it's not part of any stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for this is probably to add it to the stack using resource importing. Don't confuse a custom resource with a CDK construct. A custom resource involves deploying a lambda function and calling that function when the CloudFormation custom resource is present in your stack. A CDK construct is used to generate a CloudFormation template. It allows you to combine different resources into a single bit of code, and allows some logical decisions based on the input values.

Steps to import:

1. Make sure your current CDK is what is deployed. You cannot import resources when there are other changes.
2. Add the S3 bucket to your CDK code as if you were creating it for the first time. Make sure that all the settings are the same as what is currently deployed. This is important because the import process doesn't validate that what you have configured matches what you are importing.
3. Run `cdk synth` to generate the CloudFormation template that includes the S3 bucket.
4. In the CloudFormation console locate the stack that represents the CDK stack you are working with.
5. Select `Import resources into stack` from the `Stack actions` menu. [image]
6. Follow the prompts. When asked for the template select `Upload a template file` and select the template created by the `cdk synth` command (hint: it will be in cdk-out). You will be prompted to add the bucket name. This should be the bucket that you are wanting to add to this stack.
7. Once that is done you can modify the bucket as if it were created by your stack.

One thing to note. CDK includes some meta-data in the CloudFormation template. This value must be the same as what is currently deploy or it will be seen as a change and you won't be able to perform the import. You can copy the values from what is currently deployed and manually edit the template created by `cdk synth` to match that.

Answer (score -1):

Need to access the CfnBucket reference of the testBucket and add lifecycle rules to it.

```
const testBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'TestBucket', {
            bucketArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx')
       testBucket.node.root.addLifecycleRule({prefix: 'short', expiration:3, enabled:true})
       testBucket.node.root.addLifecycleRule({prefix: 'long', expiration:7, enabled:true})
```

Comment: I believe the question was about adding it to an existing S3 bucket (i.e. a bucket not created in the stack).

Comment: @R.T. try to add the lifecycleRules property, then run cdk diff to see the changesets. It should tell you if a new bucket is created or the specified existing bucket is updated. ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html#cli-diff

Comment: I just checked, and this doesn't work. ```lifecycleRules``` is not a property of ```BucketAttributes```

Comment: My bad, I edited the answer, please have a try again

Comment: You can't modify an S3 bucket you have added to your CDK code via fromBucketAttributes. That bucket is only useful as a reference, for things like creating permissions.

Comment: Noted my mistakes because IBucket interface does not provide any methods related to lifecycle. So I changed the answer to get the CfnBucket reference of the testBucket. Then I used the addLifecycleRule method on the reference. Hope it works!

Comment: @kayuapi_my Hey thanks for the edit! I'm a bit confused with the parentheses here - if I put ```testBucket.node.root.addLifecycleRule``` inside ```fromBucketAttributes```, then it shows ```Variable 'testBucket' is used before being assigned.```. If I put it outside, it then says ```Property 'addLifecycleRule' does not exist on type 'IConstruct'.```

Comment: It has to be outside,

`const testBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'TestBucket', {
            bucketArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxx'});
       (testBucket.node.root as CfnBucket).addLifecycleRule({prefix: 'short', expiration:3, enabled:true})
       (testBucket.node.root as CfnBucket).addLifecycleRule({prefix: 'long', expiration:7, enabled:true})`

Comment: @kayuapi_my I tried that, and this gives me the error ```Property 'addLifecycleRule' does not exist on type 'IConstruct'.```. I just checked the type of ```testBucket.node.root```, and it's IConstruct, not CfnBucket.